# Why Classes of System.IO is not available in my code

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am using this code

```
var httpClient = new HttpClient();
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.TransferEncodingChunked = true;
var content = new MultipartFormDataContent ();
var imageContent = new StreamContent (new System.IO.FileStream ("my_path.jpg", 
        System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read, System.IO.FileShare.Read));
    imageContent.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse ("image/jpeg");
    content.Add(imageContent, "image", "image.jpg");
await httpClient.PostAsync(Constants.UploadProfilePic+userId+"/photo", content);
```

but as u can see in this image of Xamarin Studio
many classes of System.Io is not available in xamarin forms.
Why it is so ? 
https://developer.xamarin.com/api/field/System.IO.FileMode.Open/
even xamarin doc says it should be there..

[image]

I am new to Xamarin development and looks like I am missing something as this is happening many times with me with other classes/namespaces as well.

even ref of System.Io is added..
[image]

Comment: Have you got the correct project references set?

Comment: I think that's because Xamarin is Android/iOS specific. However you can get them if you add the correct references.

Comment: If this is a PCL project, many System.IO operations are not supported because not all of the underlying platforms support them (Windows Phone only allows IsolatedStorage).   You will need to use DependencyService to inject the behavior into your app, or a package like PCLStorage.

Comment: it is xamarin forms based project where one shared project is PCL

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/working-with/files/

Answer (score 1):

For me it is working when I moved the code from Shared PCL project to iOS project.